# Spark : anti-join two DStreams

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I can do JOINs on two Spark DStreams like :

```
val joinStream = stream1.join(stream2)
```

Now, what if I need to filter out all the records that weren't JOINed. Essentially, something like `stream1.anti-join(stream2)`. Is this possible somehow?

Thanks and appreciate any help!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you mean by anti-join

Comment: JOINs happen between records which have a common Key right? I need all records from both the streams which does not have a common Key to JOIN.

Comment: something like http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-9xB6dMw3mcY/UIGn0glldYI/AAAAAAAAAEo/H8AkcRYvUHk/s1600/sql-left-outer-join-where-table-is-null-or-table-is-null.png ?

Comment: I have never tried it on a stream. I'm not sure it even exists.

Comment: Basically you have to do a `full_outer` join, and then filter out the records that don't have `null` values on either side of the resulting joined row.

Comment: @DavidGriffin Yes, you are correct. I can filter only the records which have None on either side of the resulting Stream's value. Thanks!

Comment: I put this in an answer, feel free to go right ahead and accept it. `;-)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you had these:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(
  (1, "one"),
  (2, "twow"),
  (3, "three"),
  (4, "four"),
  (5, "five")
))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(
  (1, "otherOne"),
  (4, "otherFour"),
  (5,"otherFive"),
  (6,"six"),
  (7,"seven")
))

val antiJoined = rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).filter(r => r._2._1.isEmpty || r._2._2.isEmpty)

antiJoined.collect foreach println
(6,(None,Some(six)))
(2,(Some(twow),None))
(3,(Some(three),None))
(7,(None,Some(seven)))
```